# NPAPI replacement (Native messaging host) for invoking external application not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, chrome-native-messaging

I have A Firebreath plugin which does the same for me, but since its support is being dropped in chrome, I have to look for an alternative. After having a look at the alternatives, **Native messaging host** looks like the best option for my case. I created the following com.mycompany.testapp.json

```
{
  "name": "com.mycompany.testapp",
  "description": "My test app",
  "path": "/usr/bin/testapp",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://jhvgchjavcjhspehlmfjbhpllakficickbkk/"
  ]
}
```

and copied it to directory:

```
/home/abc/.config/google-chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.mycompany.testapp.json
```

But my app is not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It actually turned out that Chrome 33 on Ubuntu does not look into **/home/abc/.config/google-chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/** for the json. Putting the json inside **/etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts** fixed the problem